# Format data frame rows rather than columns

Tags: r

I have a table of trended data.

```
ga_sessions_combined <-
structure(list(Metric = structure(1:7, .Label = c("Users", "Engaged Users", 
"Transactions", "Revenue", "ConversionRate", "Bounce Rate", "$/User"
), class = "factor"), ym_201904 = c(157664, 79295, 5764, 609172.887628, 
0.0365587578648265, 0.497063375279075, 3.86374116873858), ym_201905 = c(199340, 
103879, 5744, 673063.435872, 0.0288150897963279, 0.478885321561152, 
3.3764594956958), ym_201906 = c(169971, 90557, 4899, 566247.290325, 
0.0288225638491272, 0.467220878855805, 3.33143471724588), ym_201907 = c(161346, 
88059, 4223, 580408.759911, 0.0261735648854016, 0.454222602357666, 
3.5972925260682), ym_201908 = c(132702, 70701, 3106, 424807.71545, 
0.0234058265888984, 0.467219785685219, 3.20121562184443), ym_201909 = c(164160, 
96124, 3841, 724958.93068, 0.0233979044834308, 0.414449317738791, 
4.41617282334308), ym_201910 = c(217227, 118041, 4448, 798116.2282, 
0.0204762759693777, 0.456600698808159, 3.67411154322437), ym_201911 = c(970864, 
604606, 27713, 4859788.602792, 0.0285446777303515, 0.37724954267539, 
5.00563271765355), ym_201912 = c(1180689, 671162, 59536, 9447240.17602, 
0.0504247943361884, 0.431550560731912, 8.00146370129645), ym_202001 = c(216816, 
109637, 5057, 738079.024166, 0.0233239244336211, 0.494331599143975, 
3.40417231277212), ym_202002 = c(204113, 145975, 4847, 720506.474953, 
0.0237466501398735, 0.284832421256853, 3.52993917561841), ym_202003 = c(324266, 
229438, 8341, 1196234.593648, 0.0257227091338592, 0.292438923599761, 
3.68905341185323)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), .Names = c("Metric", "ym_201904", "ym_201905", "ym_201906", 
"ym_201907", "ym_201908", "ym_201909", "ym_201910", "ym_201911", 
"ym_201912", "ym_202001", "ym_202002", "ym_202003"))
```

When I run this data frame in a shiny app it looks like this:

[image]

I would like to format the table based on the column 'Metric', almost like dplyr verbs but with the column names being the first row.

For the first 3 rows, Users, Engaged Users and Transactions, I would like to format with `scales::comma_format()` to use commas for thousands like 1,000.

For the revenue and '$/User' rows I would like to format with `scales::dollar_format()`

For the Conversion and Bounce rate rows I would like to format them as `scales::percent_format()`

How can I do this?

Comment: you should use `DT` functions such as `formatCurrency`. See [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the tip but those still appear to apply across columns rather than rows

Comment: My fall back might be to transpose, make the existing columns rownames and the Metric column the columns. Then transpose back.

Comment: Yes, I think it is the easiest way

Comment: As I said under @Alan Dursun's answer, transpose the data, use `DT` functions on it and transpose it back won't work because using `DT` functions implies to change your data in `datatable` and we can't transpose a `datatable` object (so we can't transpose your data back to its original form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but it's easier to transpose your dataframe.  Here is a `tidyr` approach:

```
library(tidyr)
ga_sessions_combined %>% 
  gather(key = period, value = value, 2:ncol(ga_sessions_combined)) %>% 
  spread(key = names(ga_sessions_combined)[1], value = "value")
```

Edit:

if you want to keep it in wide format, I think this works, but everything is converted to character:

```
ga_sessions_combined %>% 
  gather(key = period, value = value, 2:ncol(ga_sessions_combined)) %>% 
  spread(key = names(ga_sessions_combined)[1], value = "value") %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches("Users|Engaged Users|Transactions")), funs(prettyNum(., big.mark=","))) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches("Rate")), funs(scales::percent(., accuracy = 0.01))) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains("$/User"), contains("Revenue")), funs(scales::dollar(.))) %>% t()
```

If long format is acceptable, then just drop the `t()` at the end.

Comment: the problem is that we need to change this data in a `datatable` object to apply the `format*` functions on it, but then we can't use `spread` or `gather` on a `datatable` object to go back to the original display

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm late to the party but here's how I accomplish this when it comes up.

The packages I've used here are
-tidyverse
-scales
-DT

```
# I created a new data frame so I would always have the original. I use the **across** function to convert everything to a character


ga_sessions_combined_2 <- ga_sessions_combined %>% 
  mutate(across(c(ym_201904:ym_202003), ~as.character(.)))


#Loop through columns 2 through the end of the df to gather the column indexes, and create an inner loop with the row indexes we want to format. Use however many inner loops you need to convert those rows to whatever format you want.

for(c in (2:ncol(ga_sessions_combined_2))){
  for(r1 in 1:3){
    ga_sessions_combined_2[r1,c] <- scales::comma(as.numeric(ga_sessions_combined_2[r1,c])) # rows 1-3 as comma
  }
  for(r2 in 5:7){
    ga_sessions_combined_2[r2,c] <- scales::percent(as.numeric(ga_sessions_combined_2[r2,c]),accuracy = .1) # rows 5-7 as percent
  }
  for(r3 in 4){
    ga_sessions_combined_2[r3,c] <- scales::dollar(as.numeric(ga_sessions_combined_2[r3,c]),accuracy = .01) # row 4 as dollar
  }
}

# Datatable 
ga_sessions_combined_2 %>% 
   DT::datatable(caption = "Formated by row instead of column"
                ,rownames= FALSE,
                options = list(columnDefs = list( list(className = 'dt-center',targets = "_all")),pageLength = 10))
```

The output looks like this:
[Output of DT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OLms.png)